# Single hardware point of failure with the following symptoms?

Tags: motherboard, dell-inspiron

As a preface, I'm fairly confident this question has no easy answer, and it's certainly not straightforward. Turn back now if you're not interested in a bit of a mystery.

I have a Dell Inspiron 5552 with seemingly unrelated points of "failure". Here are a few of the symptoms

- 70% of boots cut power before reaching the Dell BIOS splash
- Ungodly speaker beeps (7 of them in a group, I believe) forced me to unplug the built-in speakers
- Pre-boot System Assessment returns error 2000-0322 (LCD inverter / brightness error)
- In BIOS settings, AC adapter alternates every few seconds between 45 W (correct), unknown, 255 W, and "Not a Dell charger"
- Similarly, battery alternates between "Functioning normally", "Not a Dell battery", "Not detected", "Temporarily disabled... [due to high temperature]", and "Permanent failure"
- Power light blinks white and yellow (obviously related to the other power issues)
- Keyboard doesn't work but trackpad does

When I booted to Windows (miracle!!!) after 20 minutes of boot looping and other weirdness, the battery charges, the backlight works fine, but the System page reads "Processor:   (0 processors)", which is fascinating. The Settings System Info panel reads 4GB of RAM, but the Control Panel System info (same information presented in different format) says "Installed Memory: Not available".

This computer failed after about 1 year of light usage. Maybe 3 hours a day, 4 days a week on average, with some light traveling in a bookbag. I would guess that there is just one failure on the motherboard, but I can't figure out what sort of failure would cause such a wide range of symptoms, and "fail" so inconsistently as to have everything from "can't even get to bios splash" to "full windows boot". Anyone have any ideas? I'd like to restore it, since it's technically not that old, but I don't know what sort of issue to look for.

Edit: Sometimes I get a prompt for system or administrative password which I most certainly don't have and never set (looks like primitive Dell debugging or something). When this happens, the keyboard works. When it doesn't and I can boot to Windows, the keyboard doesn't work

Comment: You disconnected the PC speaker - I assume that means you opened it. Any noteworthy dust or signs of corrosion?

Comment: Try a known good AC Adapter.

Comment: I only partially opened it, speaker wires were easily accessible; that being said, couldn't see any dust nor corrosion. The battery and the power supply are both standard Dell stock, came with the machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the signs would seem to point to/be consistent with a partial failure of either the power supply or powrr regulation circuitry inside the laptop (paricularly if you consider the power supply as providing inadequate current until it "warns up". You should.determine which by testing against a known good Dell supply.

It is fairly common for electrolytic caps - heavily used in power supplies and regulation - to break down with time, and that is the most likely culprit.

Comment: The power supply is standard Dell, came with the machine. Same with the battery. Luckily, I have two of these machines, it should be possible to determine whether the issue lies with the AC adapter or with the machine. I'll comment again when I've tried a few things. Thanks for the thoughts, capacitors could explain a few things.

Comment: The power supply is bad, the other computer exhibited a few of the aforementioned symptoms when connected. But when I swapped the fully functional battery into the bad laptop, it still wouldn't boot, with similar results. Looks like there's something else wrong.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. It could be that faulty componentry in the laptop damaged th PSU - which I imagine is a bit unusual and bad design :(

Comment: Or perhaps the PSU damaged the laptop... probably best never to use it with the good laptop.